# Where can I find the Survey email templates?

Tags: email-template, salesforce-survey

According to [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=concept_send_email_template.htm&type=5) from the docs, we can customize the survey invitation emails. But I can't find the template anywhere in Setup to customize them. Where can I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightning Templates are their own Object and aren't found in Setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for "email templates" from App laucher, not in the Setup